# Creating Time Spans in R in 12 hour format

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create to a span of 1:24 hours in R with the desired display as 1 am, 2 am....12 noon, 1 pm,2 pm.....12 midnight. I have created it for 1:11 am and then 12 pm through looping but not getting how to again write 1:11 pm and 12 midnight. If anyone can pls help me on this, would be grateful.

```
x<-2017
y<-(1)
z<-"AM"
repeat{
  cat("Welcome to India",x,y,z,"\n")
  x<-x+1
  y<-y+1
  if(y<12){
    z="AM"
  }
  else{
    z="PM"
  }

  if(x>2028) break
}
```

Thanks in advance.